# javascript to JSON save dynamic property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i"m with basic knollage in javascript,
i"m trying to get data from user and use it as json properties as following

```
<th colspan="2"><input id="dc_name" name='dc[name]'></input></th>
$(".save_asJSON").click(function(){
        var dcname = {};document.getElementById("dc_name").value
        var jsonobj = {
            DCes: {
                 dcname: {
                    name : dcname,
                    .....
                }
            }
        };
        console.log(jsonobj);
    });
```

the fist dcname use (and here is my problem) - displayed as string dcname 
the second dcname use give the value as it should.

i need the json file this way, any idea how can I achieve  this

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialise your json with empty values and then set its value with the input like

```js
var jsonobj = {
            DCes: {}
        };
$(".save_asJSON").click(function(){
        var dcname =  document.getElementById("dc_name").value
        jsonobj.DCes[dcname] = {name: dcname}
        console.log(jsonobj);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<th colspan="2"><input id="dc_name" name='dc[name]'></input></th>
<button class="save_asJSON">Click</button>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the replay, but it still give me the same results. i need both "dcname" to be changed to the  input value.

Comment: What do you expect to get,

Comment: {
  "DCes": {
    "equnix-sin": {
      "name": "equinix-sin"
    }
  }
}

Comment: i know it is not making any sense how i built my json file, but it's already done and jinja2 file are built on top of this json structure .  
now i"m just building a web interface to make it esasy for users

Comment: Glad to have helped :)